# Disable active numbering sequence or switch to manual for an Acumatica API insert

Tags: acumatica

I have an Acumatica instance which requires a Purchase Order auto-numbering sequence.  I am also inserting Purchase Orders via REST API (v17.200.001) which I want to number differently. I'd like to either disable the auto-numbering or switch to a different numbering sequence for an API call to insert a Purchase Order. Is this possible via API, or does it only use the active numbering sequence?  Is there any other way to accomplish this?  I've seen examples using row event handlers to switch sequences, but I've not found anything yet for doing this for an API call.

Answer (score 0):

Numbering sequence used are configured in the preference pages:
[image]

You can choose 2 different numbering sequences based on 'Blanket' POSetup.StandardPONumberingID or 'Regular' POSetup.RegularPONumberingID purchase order types:
[image]

If your API process creates blanket order and your other process create regular order then you could choose a manual numbering sequence only for blanket orders. But I guess that's not what you're trying to do.

I don't have a simple solution to suggest, I think Acumatica customization will be required to achieve the desired goal with API calls.

A starting point could be trying to modify the value of the numbering sequences in POOrderEntry graph. They are found in the POSetup DataView: `PXSetup<POSetup> POSetup`.

Ideally you would discriminate which sequence to use based on the POOrder OrderType.

Comment: My API call is already inside a customization.  I have looked into how to switch sequences before or during an API call, but I haven't had any luck finding a way to accomplish this. Will an API insert or update of a PO trigger a RowPersisting event that I could change the key value in its handler?